# Is It Secure to connect to Firebase database directly from Angular?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am building an Angular app which will store the data in Firebase. [samples](https://medium.com/factory-mind/angular-firebase-typescript-step-by-step-tutorial-2ef887fc7d71) show that the apps are directly connecting to the backend by putting the Firebase connection info right in the app's environment. I started browser debugger and I am able to see the info to my Firebase database in the debugger. I understand that I can restrict the users to only my app users with Firebase auth and rules, but is this how everyone develops using Firebase?

Wouldn't it be more secure to have the Firebase DB hidden behind a Web API and have the Angular app call the Web API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is ok that you can find your Firebase configuration in the debugger when examining your front-end. This is how Firebase is meant to be used and it is the most common approach.

Would it be more secure to have your Firebase database hidden behind a Web API? In my opinion no. As long as you set up the security rules correctly your data is secure. But that depends on you understanding how the security rules work and configuring them correctly of course.

I would recommend staying with the approach of connecting directly to the database, and not through an API. Some of the reason that Firebase is so easy to work with is the fact that you can connect directly to it, you don't need to build your own API.

Comment: Thanks. I will learn the rules and see if its powerful. IMO, if you hide the DB details behind GCFs, we can reduce the surface area of attack.

Comment: going through https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/index. it is helpful